# SAML(PHP) using onelogin toolkit

Tags: php, saml-2.0, onelogin

I set up the SAML(PHP) using onelogin toolkit. It is redirecting to the Onelogin login page. Once given the users credential it is redirecting to the 405 error page.

Answer (score 0):

**Question**: Once given the users credential it is redirecting to the 405 error page.

**Answer**:
405 error (Method Not Allowed) indicates an incorrect method (post, get, etc.) is applied to SAML assertion consumer service endpoint such as "/saml/acs".

(I) The most popular SAML assertion consumer service endpoint of SAML SP web application provides POST REST, for example,

```
    <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://sp.example.org/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST" index="1"/>
```

(II) Chrome network debugger indicates that 
(II.a) a POST request is made to the acs URL, success (302 Found)
(II.b) a GET request is made to the acs URL, failure (405 error).

**Resolution**:
(I) Log in to your OneLogin organization (e.g., https://example.onelogin.com/ for a company called "example.com") as an administrator,
Click **APPS > Company Apps**,
on the **Company Apps** screen,
Select your SAML SP web application, e.g., **SAML Test Connector (SP Shibboleth)**,
Configure OneLogin SAML IdP with your SAML SP web application,
 
and ensure that you enter SAML assertion consumer service HTTP-POST endpoint of your SAML SP web application into **Configuration > Application Details ACS (Consumer) URL*** (required).

Note that OneLogin supports HTTP-POST (POST request) instead of HTTP-REDIECT (GET request) by default.

OneLogin uses POST request (NOT Get request) to deliver SAML SAML assertion verification request to your web application/SAML SP's assertion consumer service endpoint.

(II) [The 2-Minute Guide to Fixing HTTP Error 405 (Method Not Allowed)](https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/http-405-method-not-allowed) provides three (3) practical methods to debug HTTP Error 405 for general web request (not limited to SAML assertion verification request).